# How to get only date (DD-MM-YYYY) format not time with date using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using moment.js for formatting dates:

```
const dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
setValue('startDate', moment(booking.startDate, dateFormat));
```

I want the date to be `01-06-2020` instead of `2020-06-01T07:33:04.392Z`. Any idea, because I don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example for how to format an instance of moment.js as DD-MM-YYYY:

```js
const dateString = moment("2020-06-01T12:00:00").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
console.log({ dateString });
```

This gives the following in the console:

```
{ dateString: '01-06-2020' }
```

It'd be good to read more about moment's `format` function and [the standard W3C date and time formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

This is literally explained in the Momentjs frontpage https://momentjs.com/.
First you add your datetime to moment, then call the format function. Like this.

```
 moment('2020-06-01T07:33:04.392Z').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

This returns `"01-06-2020"`